# Open dgn and a referenced raster files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dgn

I have a dgn file that have a raster file referenced to it. If I open it in Bentley Microstation it understands where to place the raster.

If I open the dgn I get 3 layers (point, line and area) and the raster is a separate layer and not placed correct.

Is it possible to achieve this in QGIS ?
The raster files are in CIT format

Comment: is the file an attachment in Microstation? not sure on CIT raster format - can you convert it to geoTiff?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No its not an attachment. Its refererenced via raster managar. SO Microstation stores information within the dgn file of what raster files are connected, are what extent and sixe they have.
But QGIS doesnt seem to be able to handle that information.
Yes I can convert the cit to a geoTiff, but dont know how do get the extent, and size it should have.